# User names are getting cut off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Take a look at:

[image]

This is from the [Questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions) view of the home page.

Also happening on the [question view page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48570/i-want-to-assign-a-role-to-a-user-after-he-confirms-his-email):

[image]

[This is the user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/10909/raghavendra-channarayappa).  I can't comment whether this is a real name or not (but I assume it is).  If so, it is a bummer that it is being cut off.

Comment: There is a similar [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers) on MSO which has been marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Yes, this is by design. There is only so much space for the various page elements, so a reasonable size has to be selected. There is no way to support unlimited name lengths. Just ask [Krungthepmahanakonbowornratanako-
sinmahintarayudyayamahadilopono-
paratanarajthaniburiromudomrajni-
wesmahasatarnamornpimarnavatarsa-
titsakattiyavisanukamphrasit](http://anse.rs/fPqKy) or Adolph Blaine Charles David Earl Frederick Jack Gerald Hubert Irvin John Kenneth Lloyd Martin Nero Oliver Paul Quincy Randolph Sherman Thomas Uncas Victor William Xerxes Yancy Zeus Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorft Senior